# How to braid a ribbon knot

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds, braid-groups

Is there any algorithm known for braiding ribbon knots? More specifically I need to braid a generic ribbon knot presented as boundary of a ribbon surface= union of two 0-handles and one 1-handle. (Unfortunately MO did not allow me to add a picture).

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is in the paper

> Lee Rudolph, [Braided surfaces and Seifert ribbons for closed braids](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/rudolph.pdf), Comment. Math. Helvetici **58** (1983), 1–37.

In fact, in Section 3 Rudolph proves that every ribbon surface is isotopic to one arising from a braid (in a very concrete way, explained in detail in the paper), which is a lot stronger than what you ask for.